# 2 Relay H bridge design

Tags: h-bridge, actuator

I am wanting to design an H bridge to control a linear actuator. 12vdc motor, max current 3.2A under load, and has built-in travel limit switches (ie motor stops at full extension and retraction). There are two wires, for + and - , the polarity needs to be reversed (sorry, I’m sure this is pretty standard stuff so far).

The control I will be using is a 3 wire system ... - 12v, + 12v, and switched + 12v. The constant power is routed direct, whereas the switch wire comes from an ECU. The ECU does have internal H bridges, however if I program it for this operation, it cannot handle the current draw (there will be up to 16 of these actuators).

I have ‘borrowed’ a circuit board from another device (motor driven valve) which works, as per the pic below. However that contains its own limit switches (top right and top left) which I don’t need. The power supply to the motor in centre top, with supply power and switching DIN plug bottom right.

I’d like to design/build something similar, and the actuator will only need to extend or retract fully, and I do not need any speed control. Pretty much the same as the pic but without the limit circuits.

Am hoping someone can help me with this.[image]

Comment: Does the ECU supply only one control line and you will have 16 ECUs? Or does the ECU support 16 control lines? Do you intend on moving all the solenoids at the same moment, all 16 of them? Or will they be individually controlled at different times? Is the \$\pm 12 \:\text{V}\$ coming from "the" ECU? Or is this a separate supply system that powers both the ECU as well as the solenoids? Does the ECU control line provide a full \$\pm 12 \:\text{V}\$ swing at the output? Or does it go to ground at one state or the other?

Comment: The ECU will have 16 individual control lines, and each us controlled individually. The power supply powers both the ECU and the power to the solenoids. The ECU provides 12v, and go to ground the other state. Sometimes the 16 lines will ‘operate’ sequentially, at other times all at once. (Is a control mechanism for seeding according to prescription map ... auto section control). The aim is to design/build these h bridges to be installed on each of the 16 actuators. Smaller machines will only require 12 or 8.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm absorbing you correctly, you would ground one side of the solenoid and you want the H-bridge to have access to a bipolar power supply so that you can operate the solenoid in either direction. Yes? You already know that you could use two h-bridges to make up a full bridge and therefore no longer need a bipolar supply but could just use a single power supply rail, but you do NOT want to do that. Yes?

Comment: You are also aware that there is a [UC2950T](https://www.ti.com/store/ti/en/p/product/?p=UC2950T) H-bridge IC that can handle your current fine, and can also handle your 24 V bipolar voltage separation, too, but you aren't interested in ICs but instead want relays. Yes?

Comment: I’ll try to simplify so it’s clearer (to me as well) ... there will be constant power to the new circuit board, directly from the power supply (in this case 12v from battery/alternator). This will have the actuator fully extended (ie the DC motor will spin until the rod is fully extended and the limit switch prevents motor stalling). When the ECU provides 12v on the switch wire, the polarity of the current output from the circuit board will need to be reversed, to cause the DC motor to reverse rotational direction , thereby retracting the actuator until the limit switch is reached.

Comment: In other words, constant power to the board, with a switch wire (+ 12v) from the ECU when the actuator is to be retracted.

Comment: An H bridge IC would be fine ... I’m just after the most robust solution as it will be attached to moving machinery

Comment: The solenoid, though, is quite "modest" I'd imagine and can be safely driven by an h-bridge IC such as the UC2950T. You can choose one IC per solenoid with a bipolar supply or else two ICs per solenoid with a single supply rail voltage. Either works. One advantage with the single rail is that your ECU, which drives +12 V or else +0 V at its output, will require less thinking when driving two ICs per solenoid. But it's not hard, to be honest, either way you decide to go. That said, if you use relays then you can just use cheap BJTs to drive them.

Comment: I can't weigh your trade-offs for you, though. There are a number of avenues. You'll have to do the balancing, I fear. Unless you add more detailed thinking processes on your part to help us gain access to what's weighing on your mind. Your internal state of mind is inaccessible to us and we also aren't blessed with your experience and knowledge of your own area. So that's a problem. All we do is wind up throwing ideas against the wall, hoping some stick.

Comment: I'm a little unsure about the way you're describing power supply you have when you refer to "-12v & +12v". So just to clarify: do you have a single 12v supply, or do you have a dual supply with +12v & -12v with 0v in the middle for a total of 24v?

Comment: Sorry, it’s single power supply (from battery/alternator) 12v which supplies power to ECU (and control console) and also direct to the board. So 12vdc and earth or 0vdc might be a better way of describing it. I want the main supply to bypass the ECU so only the switch wire will be coming from there. So the switch wire, when powered from the ECU (12vdc) just needs to reverse the polarity of the existing power when it is live. And reverse back when the switch wire is 0vdc. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the schematic, using one DPDT relay per actuator. The limit switches and diodes, in-built in the actuator, are not shown.

[image]